# boost variant return type

Tags: c++, boost

I have a question about `boost::variant` and correct usage of it in methods. For instance, I have classes like `Stuff` and `User`
and I have function (pseudo code):

```
boost::variant<User*, Stuff*> HashTable::getPersonByKey(string login, string password, string list_type)
  {
    int index = hash(login, password);
    boost::variant<User*, Stuff*> temp_u, temp_s;
    if (list_type == "User")
    {
        if (user_array[index].getPerson(login, password))
        {
            temp_u = user_array[index].getPerson(login, password);
            //returns User* 
            //maybe something like variant<User* , Stuff*> (temp_u);
            return VARIANT
        }
    }
    else if (list_type == "Stuff")
    {
        if (user_array[index].getPerson(login, password))
        {
            temp_s = stuff_array[index].getPerson(login, password);
            //returns Stuff* 
            //maybe something like variant<User* , Stuff*> (temp_s);
            return VARIANT
        }
    }
    return boost::variant<User*, Stuff*>();
 }
```

How is the return supposed to be?

Can I make something even more complex like ...

```
boost::variant<boost::variant<User*, Stuff*>, boost::variant<User*, Stuff*>>getPerson()
{
  boost::variant<boost::variant<User*, Stuff*>, boost::variant<User*, Stuff*>> temp_user1, temp_stuff1 , 
  temp_user2 , temp_stuff2;
  temp_u = user_array[index].getPerson(login, password);
  return variant<variant <User* , Stuff*> ,variant <User* , Stuff*>> (temp_user1);
}
```

Should I somehow explicitly show to which variant `temp_person` belongs to?
Will it be a problem to get objects out of this?

Comment: Don't you want inheritance instead ?

Comment: In `boost::variant<boost::variant<User*, Stuff*>, boost::variant<User*, Stuff*>>`, the 2 types are identical, it doesn't make sense for `variant`.

Comment: `return user_array[index].getPerson(login, password);` or `return temp_u;` should work.

Comment: Why a variant of pointers? What are the pointers for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think about `boost::variant` as a improved C++ `union`.

For example, as a `union`, `boost::variant<User*, Stuff*>` can store either a pointer to `User` or a pointer to `Stuff` but unlike a `union`, you can check which type is stored.

In your example you declare:

```
boost::variant<User*, Stuff*> getPersonByKey(string login, string password, string list_type)
```

It means that `getPersonByKey` returns either a `User*` or a `Stuff*`. You can construct a variant from any of their options, so you can just return one pointer of those types.

The method `getPerson()` is not declared in your example so I cannot fully rewrite your example. However, if `getPerson()` returns an `User*`, you can directly return its value and it will be converted to a `boost::variant<User*, Stuff*>` containing the returned value.

Note that `boost::variant<User*, Stuff*>` **must be** either `User*` or `Stuff*`. It cannot be empty. So, if you return a default `boost::variant<User*, Stuff*>`, you are actually returning a default pointer to `User`.

As boost::variant is used to hold one of the template parameters, it makes no sense to declare it like:

```
boost::variant<T, T>
```

Because it means that you can store either a T or and T. In this case, you can just use a T type.

It is very easy to check which type is store in the variant. The easiest way is to use the `get` method:

```
User **user = boost::get<User*>(&variant);
```

The variable `user` will get a pointer to the stored value if a pointer to `User` was stored or `nullptr` if a `Stuff` pointer was stored. There are more ways to access the value, like using visitors.

You can find more information in the [variant tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic).